# missing 1 required positional argument: 'd'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola soy nueva básicamente usando Python y estoy haciendo un programa interactivo para cambiar el contraste de una imagen pero me sale un error sobre la falta de un argumento cuando ingreso el parámetro d que es el de controlador slider

```
def plot_image(image,title=''):
  plt.title(title, size=20)
  plt.imshow(image)
  plt.axis('off')
def contrast(c, d):
    return 0 if c<70 else (255 if c>150 else cont(255*c-22950)/d) 
def contraste (d):
  
  im8_r,im8_g,im8_b,_ = im8.split()
  im_t3 = im8.point(contrast)
  im8_r,im8_g,im8_b,_ = im_t3.split()
 
  plot_image(im_t3,'imagen transformada')
 
widgets.interact(contraste, d=widgets.IntSlider(value=7,
    min=0,
    max=10,
    step=1,
    description='Contraste:',
    disabled=False,
    continuous_update=False,
    orientation='horizontal',
    readout=True,
    readout_format='d'));
```

y me sale este error

```
return self._new(self.im.point_transform(scale, offset))
   1576             # for other modes, convert the function to a table
-> 1577             lut = [lut(i) for i in range(256)] * self.im.bands
   1578 
   1579         if self.mode == "F":

TypeError: contrast() missing 1 required positional argument: 'd'
```

Answer (score 1):

Desconozco el entorno (o framework) desde el que estás trabajando, pero a la vista de esta línea de código:

```
  im_t3 = im8.point(contrast)
```

parece que lo que `point` espera como parámetro es una función a la que invocará en algún momento, pues tú le estás pasando un nombre de función `contrast`.

Esta función la tienes declarada así, con dos parámetros (aparentemente el primero sería el color de un pixel y el segundo algún tipo de factor de escala).

```
def contrast(c, d):
    return 0 if c<70 else (255 if c>150 else cont(255*c-22950)/d)
```

Por otro lado, a la vista del error:

```
TypeError: contrast() missing 1 required positional argument: 'd'
```

parece que cuando la función `contrast` es invocada, se le pasa un solo parámetro, ya que se está quejando de que falta el segundo `d`.

En resumen, creo que el problema es que la función que `im8.point()` espera, ha de ser una función que reciba un solo parámetro, que sería el color, y en cambio la función que tú le estás pasando (`contrast`) espera dos parámetros.

Una forma de adaptarlo para que funcione sería pasarle a `im8.point()` una función que espere un solo parámetro (el color) y que llame a `contrast()` pasándole dos (el color que ha recibido como parámetro y un valor de `d` que saque de otra parte, en este caso del parámetro recibido por `contraste()`.

En definitiva, creo que el siguiente código arreglaría el problema, aunque sin poder probarlo y desconociendo tu *framework* no puedo estar 100% seguro:

```
def contraste (d):
  
  im8_r,im8_g,im8_b,_ = im8.split()
  im_t3 = im8.point(lambda c: contrast(c, d))
  im8_r,im8_g,im8_b,_ = im_t3.split()
 
  plot_image(im_t3,'imagen transformada')
```

Como ves he cambiado lo que le paso a `im8.point()` por una función `lambda` de un solo parámetro `c`. Desde la lambda llamo a `contrast()` pasándole los dos parámetros que espera, `c` es lo que la lambda ha recibido como parámetro y `d` es el valor de esa variable dentro de la función `contraste()`.

Answer (score 1):

La función `contrast` está definida con dos parámetros, `c` y `d`.

La función `point` que usas en

```
im_t3 = im8.point(contrast)
```

recibe como parámetro una función que requiere un solo parámetro (el pixel siendo transformado). La función que llamas necesita dos ('c' y 'd') y sólo recibe 'c', lo que genera el error en cuestión:

```
TypeError: contrast() missing 1 required positional argument: 'd'
```

Probablemente `d` deba ser una variable global.